# White color in LS_COLORS with MSYS

Tags: msys, ls-colors

I'm using MSYS in a Windows machine. I've configured my LS_COLORS in .profile to color the files in white and folders in green:

```
LS_COLORS='fi=01;37:no=00:di=01;32'
```

I've set the text color of the window where msys.bat will be run as green, so whatever I write in the console appears in green. This, however, makes the white color I set for the files be green instead. This means the 37 won't set a white color, but the default text color of the window instead.

Is there a way to make the input appear in green and the files listed with ls appear in white?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set one of the colors for the window to be white, and then set LS_COLORS to use that color instead of color 7.  Using `3f` instead of `37` should give you color 15.

A window has 16 colors set for it, that you can see by selecting properties -> colors by right-clicking on the border.  Generally color 0 is the background and color 7 is the foreground (and many programs may assume that) though that can be changed as can the actual colors of any the 16 color codes.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. White is only set when white is chosen as the default color for the text. If green is chosen as default for window text (the input), there's no way to make it setable in LS_COLORS. 7 is equivalent to 0 (default green) and colors from a to f doesn't show any colors in fact. Using a to f will corrupt the ls command with smileys, new line characters, etc. Apparently there's no way to have a green input and white for ls outputs.